# Using CMake, what are the steps to deal with iOS certs + Info.plist, for both a distributable library, and for building an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake

I have written a cross-platform game creation library that compiles to a static/shared library with CMake as a framework. I don't need help building the iOS app itself, but instead am completely new Apple developer accounts, App ID's, signing, etc.

Here are the steps I have tentatively figured out:

1. The Framework's CMake file needs to set the target properties `FRAMEWORK` and `MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER`.
2. The user needs to create a CMakeLists.txt file for their own project. It must contain `MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER`, `MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION` and `MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING`.

I'm a bit confused on developer accounts. Does the third party library need a developer account associated with it? For `MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER` can I just specify any string I like, or do I need to register an App ID with Apple? For example, the third party library is called Cute Framework, for the identifier can I simply make up a string like `"com.cute_framework.${CF_VERSION}"`? Should I even append a version number here? Can I somehow use "iPhone Developer" for the framework?

For #2 the user needs their own developer account and can fill in the `MACOSX_BUNDLE_***` fields themselves. Will this allow XCode to automatically figure out how to sign both the user app and the library with the user's cert? What about the case of the library as a shared library? How does code signing work here?

Am I missing any major CMake steps? Overall I'm confused on how developer accounts/certs map to the associated CMake commands, and the CMake differences between a third party distributed framework and an actual iOS app.

Comment: If you are just creating a framework then no signing is required and it does not need to be associated with a developer account. The developer who uses your app will need a developer account and can sign their finished bundle, which will include your framework.

Answer (score 2):

The Bundle ID for the framework is just a unique string identifier, not tied to any specific developer account. The user's developer account has a unique Team ID (more on this below). Xcode can be configured by the user auto-magically setup code signing for both the framework and the user's app.

---

For the library/framework itself the target property `FRAMEWORK` should be set when building for an Apple device. You should also specify a framework version and identifier (`FRAMEWORK_VERSION` and `MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER`). The latter is used by Apple to uniquely identify the framework itself. When a user compiles against your library XCode will append the user's Apple Team ID onto the framework's ID to sign the framework automatically.

```
set_target_properties(my_library PROPERTIES FRAMEWORK TRUE)
set_target_properties(cute PROPERTIES
        FRAMEWORK_VERSION "1.0.0"
        MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER "org.mylibrary.static"
)
```

Note -- you cannot have any underscores in the identifier.

For the user's CMake script they can set their own target properties for both MacOS/iOS with `MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER`, `MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION` and `MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING`.

```
set_target_properties(my_game PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER "com.teamname.gamename"
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION "1.0.0"
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING "1.0.0"
)
```

When initially configuring CMake the user needs to specify some settings for iOS builds. Some great example command lines [can be seen here](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/docs/README-cmake.md). For example, to build for for simulator in a folder called `build` the user could use:

```
cmake -G "Xcode" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=iphonesimulator -DCMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=XXXXXXXXXX -Bbuild .
```

Or for iPhone/iPad:

```
cmake -G "Xcode" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=iphoneos -DCMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=XXXXXXXXXX  -Bbuild .
```

`CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM` comes from the user's Apple Developer Account, and can be found by going to [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com). It is the developer's Team ID. If the user has added their developer account to Xcode, Xcode can automatically setup code signing during the build process.

The same process can be used to build any sample applications for the library/framework, where the user can supply their Team ID via `CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM` to build + sign any sample apps that are built along with the library/framework.